# Laravel Forge Deployment fail with php 7.4 typed property on User model

Tags: laravel, deployment, laravel-forge, php-7.4

I create fresh new project in Laravel 7 with php 7.4 and on User model I have this properties:

```
* The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected array $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected array $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast to native types.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected array $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];
```

and on Laravel Homestead everything works fine but when I want to deploy app with Laravel Forge on UserSeeder I got this message:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Type of App\User::$casts must not be defined (as in class Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you're getting this error is because the `$casts` property defined in the parent class isn't typed as an `array` property but it is in your model.

According to the [PHP RFC: Typed Properties 2.0](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/typed_properties_v2#inheritance_and_variance):

> Property types are invariant. This means that the type of a (non-private) property is not allowed to change during inheritance (**this includes adding or removing property types**).

---

To get around this issue I would suggest simply removing `array` from your inherited properties.

I would also suggest reading [this article](https://stitcher.io/blog/typed-properties-in-php-74) for more information on typed properties and other PHP 7.4 changes.

Comment: Hm, In HasAttrbutes trait cast is also typed as array. In Homested (local environment) everything works fine). When I remove array I am getting different error

Comment: Did you change the `HasAttributes` (`Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Concerns`) trait to include the `array` type for the properties? AFAIK, Laravel hasn't ever added property types to its classes.

Comment: I don't understand. It's already included because all of User model property also have typed array in HasAttributes

Comment: And I don't want to change vendor files/ classes

Comment: Ah good, I was hoping you hadn't changed the vendor files. You've lost me a bit though, have you created your own `HasAttributes` trait and added that to the `User` model? Also, what is the "different" error you're getting?

Comment: Something like App\User $ must be array or something like that. I didn't create my own HasAttributes but maybe my ide change vendor HasAttributes

Comment: Ah fair enough. Either way, the `HasAttributes` trait that comes with Laravel doesn't have typed properties so the properties that are being overridden in your models shouldn't be typed either. I would suggest removing the types from your models and then reinstalling your composer dependencies (remove the vendor directory and then run `composer install`).

Comment: Thanks. I didn't try but definitely my php storm change type property in vendor. Because of that everything works fine in Homestead (local)

Comment: @Rwd Check link.